# Chamar app.service ao recarregar a página

Tags: angular

Ao iniciar a aplicação, é executado antes a função `getBanners()` do serviço `banners.service.ts` e somente depois é alterado o `this.headers` do serviço `app.service.ts`.

Caso eu troque de página, funciona normalmente. O erro só ocorre ao iniciar a aplicação.

Quero que o `banners.service.ts` execute a função somente após `this.headers` do serviço `app.service.ts` tiver sido alterado.

**banners.service.ts**

```
getBanners(){
    return this._http.get(this.appService.endpoint + 'banners', { headers: this.appService.headers })
  .toPromise()
  .then((data) => {
    data = data.json();
    return data;
  });
}
```

**app.service.ts**

```
constructor() {
    this.getContentType().then(data => {
        this.headers.set('Content-Type', data);
    });
}

private getContentType(): Promise<any> {
    return 'application/json';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em Angula 2+ você não trabalha de forma linear, esperando carregar isso ou aquilo primeiro...Tenha um serviço compartilhado entre todos os componentes. Dentro do serviço, declare uma variável que contenha o valor que você deseja compartilhar entre os componentes. Em seguida, use getter e setter para atribuir, recuperar ou modificar a variável do serviço.

> *shared.service.ts*:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService{
    headers;

    constructor(){
      this.headers = '';
    }

    setHead(token: string){
      this.headers = new Headers({
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            });;
    }

    getHead(){
      return new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
    }
}
```

> Adicione o serviço em *app.module.ts* Providers:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [ SharedService ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> Em *component.ts* injetar o serviço e usá-lo para definir, recuperar ou modificar a variável.

```
constructor(private appService: AppService) { }

  changeHead(){
    let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('User'));
    this.appService.setHead(currentUser.token);
  }


getBanners(){
    return this._http.get(this.appService.endpoint + 'banners', { headers: this.appService.getHead() })
  .toPromise()
  .then((data) => {
    data = data.json();
    return data;
  });
}
```

Comment: O nome do shared.service.ts e o serviço adicionado no Provider do AppModule não deveria ser SharedService ao invés de AppService?
Porém, mesmo alterando esses nomes, dei um console.log() do getHead() e no _header_: ele tem apenas o ____proto____

Comment: .....Deu bom???

Comment: Não funcionou. No console.log(this.sharedService.getHead()) ele me retorna body, headers, etc., mas o headers só lista o ____proto____ ao invés de listar também o 'Content-Type' e o 'Authorization'

Comment: Além disso, atualmente tenho a função getBanners() no banners.service.ts. É necessário alterar o código para o banners.components.ts como você fez no seu exemplo? Desculpe, ainda não estou muito familiarizado com o Angular.

Comment: E o `this.appService.getHead()`? você tem que usar ele. Dar um log nele...

Comment: Mas o getHead() está no servico SharedService, e não no AppService...

Comment: Isso que você não entendeu...O appService está no `constructor` do `appService`, por isso, você consegue usar o `this.appService.getHead()` que pertence ao SharedService

Comment: Não tem como usar o próprio serviço no seu próprio `constructor`

Comment: O objetivo de sua pergunta é gerar uma variável global, acessível para demais components, então a melhor forma é essa...Assim você não precisa fazer particularmente em cada um.

Comment: A função `getHead()` está no SharedService. Como que usaria ela no AppService sem importar o SharedService?

Comment: O `AppService` não deveria ter um `extends SharedService`?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer por herança nesse caso o header sempre estará certo.

```
@Injectable()
export class BannersService extends AppService{
   constructor() {
      super()
   }

   getBanners(){
        return this.httpClient.get(this.endpoint + 'banners', { headers: this.headers })     
    }
}
```

App.service.ts

```
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {    
      this.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');      
}
```